# Notification delivering at 12 AM instead of 7 AM

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to schedule a notification to be delivered at 7 AM. But it gets delivered at 12 AM. Please help me what I am doing wrong. This is my code.

```
NSString *date = @"4/14/2013 07:00";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *thisDate = [df dateFromString:date];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = thisDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];  
localNotification.alertBody = @"This is notification";
localNotification.alertAction = @"view";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.alertLaunchImage = Nil;
self.badgeCount ++;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = self.badgeCount;
localNotification.userInfo = Nil;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

I expect this notification to be delivered at 7 AM. Instead it pops up at 12 AM. What is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I bet `localNotification.timeZone` and `df.timeZone` are not the same...

Add this to your DateFormatter:

```
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

Comment: Exactly. When I see the -5 hours difference, it seems obvious.

Comment: This isn't going to help. `NSDateFormatter` defaults to the current timezone. So setting it to the default timezone is a no-op.

Comment: Unless `defaultTimeZone` has been set to something other than `localTimeZone`?